# Python Matrix Multiplication

Tags: java, python, matrix

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this python script. Would any python gurus like to translate a couple of the lines? I'm mainly talking about the last two. There seems to be a lot packed into those two lines. My main motivation is to convert this algorithm into Java.

```
u=matrix( [[1,2,2], [-2,-1,-2], [2,2,3]] )
a=matrix( [[1,2,2], [2,1,2], [2,2,3]] )
d=matrix( [[-1,-2,-2], [2,1,2], [2,2,3]] )
m=[ array([3,4,5]) ]
while m:
  for i in m:
    yield i
  g=( (i*j).getA1() for i in m for j in (u,a,d) )
  m=[ i for i in g if max is None or sum(i)<=max ]
```

Comment: Where is `max` defined? (They really shouldn't define variables named `max` since `max` is a built in function).

Comment: Without the definition of `matrix` and `max` it's hard to understand what's going on. I really don't get why there is that nested `for` with the `yield i`. Anyway, _probably_ the second last line does a 1x3 matrix times those 3x3 matrixes and probably the `getA1` return just the first row of the result(?). And the last line filters these results checking that the sum of the values inside this row is less than a certain maximum value `max`.
Anyway, are you sure that translating "literally" to Java is going to result in good and/or fast java code?

Comment: Does Java even have something analogous to `yield`? If not, a direct conversion may be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

This should be easier to convert to Java:

```
while len(m) != 0:
      for arr in m:
          queue.put(arr) # yield arr
      newm = []
      for arr in m:
          for mat in (u,a,d):
              i = multiply_array_matrix(arr, mat).getA1()
              if max_ is None or sum(i) <= max_:
                 newm.append(i)
      m = newm
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to J.F. Sebastian and some more investigation into Python (but mostly to J.F.), I was able to convert this to Java. I changed the names not only to protect the innocent, but to make it a but more self-documenting.

Replacing the yield functionality with a queue was the spark that got me on the right track. Since Java can't do the "mat in (u, a, d)" thing, I had to split that into three very similar lines. I have trimmed out a few things for this posting but in my finished code I call a method in those three lines that includes the "<= max" check.

It works incredibly faster than I expected!

```
ArrayList<int[]> resultList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
ArrayList<int[]> workingList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
workingList.add(new int[]{3, 4, 5}); // add the base triple

while(workingList.size() > 0)
{
    for (int[] triple: workingList)
        addTriple(resultList, triple);

    ArrayList<int[]> additions = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    for (int[] triple: workingList)
    {
        additions.add(multiply(triple, u));
        additions.add(multiply(triple, a));
        additions.add(multiply(triple, d));
    }
    workingList = additions;
}
```

Comment: `"mat in (u, a, d)" thing`: `ArrayList<Matrix> matrices; ... for (Matrix mat: matrices)`. I've used `queue.put(arr)` to stress the concurrent aspect of `yield` i.e., if `queue.maxsize == 1` then until `queue.get()` is called in a consumer thread the `queue.put(arr)` will block. Also it supports infinite loops (size of `resultList` is unlimited). In a single thread you could use `callback(arr)` instead of `queue.put(arr)` to achieve the same effect.